# Creating a DataFrame from a List of Dictionaries which have nested lists for their values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested-lists

I couldn't find a similar answer to my problem, so here we go: I have crawled a website and stored the data in a CSV file in the following format:

`data = [{"has_media": "false", "tags": ["e", "x", "y", "s", "f", "f"], "img_urls": [], "is_replied": "false", "is_reply_to": "false", "likes": 0, "links": [], "parent_id": "", "replies": 0, "reply_to_users": [], "comments": 1, "screen_name": "name", "text": "This is plain text retrieved from the webpage and a link http://ht.ly/25DQR and a hashtag #ecar", "text_html": "<p class=\"><s>#</s><b>electric</b></a></p>", "timestamp": "2010-08-01T09:37:20", "timestamp_epochs": 3749793792, "_id": "28829932", "_url": "/user/status/17479367564", "user_id": "1038384584", "username": "username", "video_url": ""}, {"has_media": "false", "hashtags": ["e", "o", "y", "p", "r", "s"], "img_urls": [], "is_replied": "false", "is_reply_to": "false", "likes": 0, "links": [], "parent_id": "", "replies": 0, "reply_to_users": [], "comments": 1, "screen_name": "user", "text": "New cooperative project: This is plain text retrieved from the webpage and a link http://ht.ly/25DQR and a hashtag #hello", "text_html": "<p class=\</b></a></p>", "timestamp": "2011-05-01T09:50:11", "timestamp_epochs": 18734839, "_id": "2982892", "_url": "/user/status/83982893", "user_id": "29983882", "username": "user", "video_url": ""}]`

I want to create a Data Frame from this where **each dictionary** is a **new row** and **each key** represents **a column**.

I have tried this, however it gives me only one column and appears not to recognise the dictionaries.

```
import pandas as pd
file = data.split(',')
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file)
```

Help is very much appreciated as I am new to coding and could need some help to get better at it.

Thank you!

Comment: your dict isn't valid, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I hope it is correct now :) sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: It still will not compile for me - giving a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. You may use:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{"has_media": "false", "tags": ["e", "x", "y", "s", "f", "f"], "img_urls": [], "is_replied": "false", "is_reply_to": "false", "likes": 0, "links": [], "parent_id": "", "replies": 0, "reply_to_users": [], "comments": 1, "screen_name": "name", "text": "This is plain text retrieved from the webpage and a link http://ht.ly/25DQR and a hashtag #ecar", "text_html": "<p class=\"><s>#</s><b>electric</b></a></p>", "timestamp": "2010-08-01T09:37:20", "timestamp_epochs": 3749793792, "_id": "28829932", "_url": "/user/status/17479367564", "user_id": "1038384584", "username": "username", "video_url": ""}, {"has_media": "false", "hashtags": ["e", "o", "y", "p", "r", "s"], "img_urls": [], "is_replied": "false", "is_reply_to": "false", "likes": 0, "links": [], "parent_id": "", "replies": 0, "reply_to_users": [], "comments": 1, "screen_name": "user", "text": "New cooperative project: This is plain text retrieved from the webpage and a link http://ht.ly/25DQR and a hashtag #hello", "text_html": "<p class=\</b></a></p>", "timestamp": "2011-05-01T09:50:11", "timestamp_epochs": 18734839, "_id": "2982892", "_url": "/user/status/83982893", "user_id": "29983882", "username": "user", "video_url": ""}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

By the way, you also can download it from your file using:

```
df = pd.read_json(filename, orient='records')
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the code posted (even fixing the syntax errors)

Comment: It works for me. Check with data from questions after deleting wrong quotation mark.